# Imminent drive failure: OP in need of reopening question

Tags: discussion

Earlier today I ran across [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463158/random-ext4-fs-errors) and I've already [left a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463158/random-ext4-fs-errors?noredirect=1#comment842941_463158) that OP should take a full system backup because it "felt" like a hardware error. (Intuition, old fart here)

1. Can we re-open this question ASAHP so that a well-funded answer can be posted? (or a duplicate found?). NRN to this one: if you have the rep, please re-open and leave a comment.
   <sup>(Thank you) **:-)**</sup>
2. What is this site's POV on someone leaving a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463158/random-ext4-fs-errors?noredirect=1#comment842941_463158) giving a 90% probability of an answer and [someone else](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/463219/90054) just blatantly plagiarizing said comment and posting it as an answer?

   a. Let it slide, tough luck?
   b. [Complain](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463158/random-ext4-fs-errors?noredirect=1#comment843134_463219) and post your own answer?
   c. Refer to your original comment, answer and let the community decide?
   d. Something else entirely?

Comment: As far i can see this just got reopened.

Comment: @Videonauth [answer posted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/463275/90054)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind of baffled as to why that question was closed; I went into the history thinking "it must've been massively edited after it was closed" only to find the closure was the most recent event. Reopened it now.

As for the comment: first, I'd avoid phrases like "blatantly plagiarizing". Once the `smartctl` output was posted, it became very obvious what the problem was, so anyone that looked at the question would've thought "oh, I know this".

Generally in cases where somebody thinks they know the answer but isn't certain, I recommend posting it as an answer. If you're wrong you can always delete it, but when the question gets solved in the comments somebody has to go back and convert that comment thread to an answer. A lot of times that never happens, and a lot of times it does happen but the asker has already moved on and the question sits "unresolved" forever. I see 0-answer questions that have been solved in the comments a *lot* on this site.

There's really no downside to just posting an answer upfront -- discussion about that answer can be in the answer's comments instead of mixed in with the question's comments, the answer can be edited as the problem is better understood, and as soon as the answer is right the asker can skip the "It worked!" comment and just mark the answer correct immediately.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, action and  explanation.  I try to avoid the Fastest Gun In The West approach and only post an answer when I'm 100% sure it'll work for OP on the site I'm most active [au.se] but here I'll start shooting faster!  **:-)** [Answer posted in the meantime](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/463275/90054)

Comment: "There's really no downside to just posting an answer upfront". Well, people don't like to be downvoted. So they try to write a good, detailed answer or no answer.